# Can we execute exec-maven-plugin before maven-surefire-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

Is it possible to run exec-maven-plugin before maven-surefire-plugin, what I observe during my run is maven-surefire-plugin is executing first even though the sequence in  tag is second. My scenario is to execute JAVA CLASS (using exec-maven-plugin ) which generates my testng.xml and can run that using (maven-surefire-plugin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you have an execution of the `exec-maven-plugin` bound to the `test` phase, it is normal that this execution is performed after the one of the `maven-surefire-plugin`. The reason is that you're likely dealing with a project of packaging `jar`, [which has a default binding of the Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) to the `test` phase. This default execution is always the first one invoked, regardless of where the plugin is declared in the POM. In the logs, you will spot this execution with an id of `default-test`.

There is a way to perform actions before the tests are run by leveraging [the phases invoked before the phase `test`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). In your case, your goal is to generate a test resource, the `testng.xml`, so it would be appropriate to use the `generate-test-resources` phase, whose purpose is to create resources that are needed for the tests. Therefore, you just need to specify

```
<phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
```

to the execution of the `exec-maven-plugin` generating the `testng.xml`.

Then, you can use the generated `testng.xml` with the [`suiteXmlFiles`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#suiteXmlFiles) element, see [Using Suite XML Files](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Using_Suite_XML_Files)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am not sure what I am missing here, please check the code I added to my question and let me know where and what is wrong in that. Your response will be appreciated.

Comment: @kalyanchavali This a new question, unrelated to your initial one, and I encourage you to post a new question instead. The `<sourceDirectory>src/test/java</sourceDirectory>` is concerning: why are you doing this? `src/test/java` is the test source directory, not main. Further, why the empty tags `<source />` and `<target />`? Please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have implemented:

1. I have added test script/java main class, I want to execute before Cucumber Test Suite, in following folder:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKG5P.png)
2. Added following  in POM.xml in ...

```html
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>

            <execution>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>

                        <source>src/test/java/BeforeSuite</source> <!-- source folder where Before Suite scripts are saved -->
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>

            <execution>
                <id>before-test-suite-scripts</id>
                <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>BeforeSuite.HelloBeforeSuiteScript</mainClass> <!-- <packagename>.<className> -->
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

When running `mvn clean verify`, before test suite script will run prior the test suite execution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfp0d.png)